# Zend Form: add error message after form validation

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, zend-form

How to add an error message to Zend Form element after the form was already validated?

I'm trying to add error mesages I get from `Zend_Auth` (now I'm displaying them using flashMessenger).

I tried something like this:

```
$form->getElement('username')->addErrorMessage('my message');
```

Comment: Other errors are displayed as expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the zend form documentation -

> addErrorMessage($message): add an
>   error message to display on form
>   validation errors. You may call this
>   more than once, and new messages are
>   appended to the stack.
>
> addError($message): add a message to
>   the custom error messages stack and
>   flag the form as invalid.

If your form is not marked as invalid, it probably doesn't show any error messages.  Using `addError($message)` rather than `addErrorMessage($message)` will ensure that the element is also marked invalid.

Comment: Sorry, There was a typo in my code. $form->getElement('username')->addErrorMessage('my message'); works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!$your_zend_auth_result){
    $form->getElement('username')->addError('Your Message');
    $form->markAsError();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setErrors()` method to create errors stack.
In the case, when element already has some errors you should use `addErrors()` method.
To check if element has errors you can use `hasErrors()` method